# Reading Incoming HTTP Response Bodies to CLI

Tags: http, ubuntu, firefox, httpresponse, packet-sniffers

There's a simple game that my friends and I play both in person and and online. I developed a CLI that records our in-person games (I just type in each move), but I now want to use it to record our online games. All I need to do is pipe the HTTP response bodies being sent to my browser (Firefox) to my CLI. Unfortunately. I can't figure out how to do this.

Ideally, I'm looking for a Ubuntu package that I can run from the command line that will capture and return all HTTP response bodies from a specific endpoint. I've looked into tcpdump and some simple proxy servers, but I'm not sure they do what I want them to do.

Thanks for your help! Let me know if I need to provide any further information!

Comment: MITMProxy can do this for you, and also exposes an api you can use to integrate directly with your cli: https://mitmproxy.org/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! MITMProxy does look like the correct tool. Unfortunately, using it is non-trivial, even with its documentation. If anyone could provide some guidance, I would appreciate it! Otherwise, I'll post an answer when I figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used MITMProxy as ZachChilders recommended in the comments. I found it somewhat difficult to get set up, so I'll include what directions I followed to get it up and running:

1) [Install MITMProxy.](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/#linux)

2) [Configure Firefox.](https://fernandobarillas.com/blog/2016/using-a-cfssl-ca-to-intercept/#configuring-firefox)

3) [Create Add On to parse body.](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/1487)

4) Stream data via Python to CLI (TODO).